# Who actually is Black Widow's pair?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow

I was going through a lot of Marvel questions, and I read that Hawkeye and Black Widow were a couple but then another person says Captain America and Black Widow were a couple. And I always thought the Hulk and her was a couple, because they always looked at each other really funny.

So who is her main pair/item?

Comment: I've tagged this with the MCU tag as that appears to be what you're asking about, however, if it is not please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Why she can't date more than one? In MCU she paired up with HUlk but in comcis there are many

Comment: @SteveHarrington sorry I was asking about the main one. And I watch the normal Avengers series, and then it's always her and The Hulk. Well, in Endgame she and Hawkeye got a little involved though.

Comment: @AngelicWarrior people can love multiple people in different time or even same time. Spider-Mna and Batman have so many.

Comment: @SteveHarrington Spider-Man only has MJ.

Comment: @AngelicWarrior maybe you don't know about Gwen Stacy who was main love interest before she died, recently he got Silk too, here is the list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Spider-Man_supporting_characters#Peter_Parker's_love_interests

Comment: @SteveHarrington The OP seems to be talking about the MCU only.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot taht was not clear from OP post but after accepting your answer it seems to eb pretty clear.

Comment: You can't delete this post now and there's no reason to anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No one

In the MCU Nat doesn't really have a love interest, most of the time.She flirts with Cap in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier* and they kiss but that's just to avoid drawing attention to themselves.

Later on we see she's close to Hawkeye, however, that is a close friend friendship and not a love interest. She's even the only Avenger to know about Clint's family and safe house. So much so that they were naming their newborn after her.

Lastly, she's close to Bruce as we see in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* and there could actually have been a potential for a couple between them. The both liked each other but Bruce was scared to make the leap into the relationship. All chances of redeeming that were killed off though as Hulk left Earth at the end of *Avengers: Age of Ultron* as we find out in *Thor: Ragnarok*. He's gone for so long that Nat moves on and it's "awkward" when they finally meet again in *Avengers: Infinity War*. However, it's clear from their interaction in the film they've moved on from each other.

> **Natasha Romanoff:** Hi, Bruce.
>
> **Bruce Banner:** Nat.
>
> **Sam Wilson:** [Whispering] This is awkward.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Infinity War*</sub>

Comment: Hmm. So she's closer to Bruce?

Comment: @AngelicWarrior Prior to Hulk leaving at the end of AoU and romantically, yes. For her closest friend, that's probably Clint.